# Connect to router through wifi as backup

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I have my desktop computer connected to the router through an ethernet connection using a PLC adapter (Power Line Carrier). My setup is:

- Living room: router --[eth]--> PLC
- Office: PLC --[eth]--> computer

I have to work away from my office, so I wanted to add a UPS to the whole setup. I found that Salicru has a small DC UPS that I could connect my router to. Then I can add another UPS to my office computer. Voila! Looks I have it, but then the PLC part is missing! If power is cut-off, my router still works, computer works, but ethernet does not!

So, I am thinking of adding a wifi dongle to my computer and configure Ubuntu to be able to connect using WiFi, whenever ethernet is not available (e.g. power outage taking out PLC), or have it always connected and have it "intelligently" use the best connection.

How can I set that up?

PS: In my laptop, if both ethernet and wifi are connected, internet does not work well, but when I disconnect wifi (or eth), it starts working.

Comment: Read about static routing.